# problem with paired t-test: not all arguments have the same length

Tags: r

I want to do paired t-test with a data frame. I think I grouped them right but do not know why it reports the error: 
Error in complete.cases(x, y) : not all arguments have the same length.

centre_g is my data frame containing all the info I want to use in my analysis. Paired t-test is a right way to do it.

```
str(centre_g)
# Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   
# 24 obs. of  17 variables 
# (I will only list two variables that is used for my anaysis):
# $ BA: Factor w/ 2 levels "after","before": 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...
# $ Pb: num  437 1183 1465 3105 NA ...
```

I used to extract "before" and "after" for "Pb", i.e. I extracted two vectors in the data frame, and did paired t-test, it works fine

```
(tResult <- t.test(before$Pb, after$Pb, paired = TRUE))
```

but when I tried to do the paired t-test directly on my data frame, it has the error message mentioned in the question

```
(tResult <- t.test(Pb ~ BA, data = centre_g, paired = TRUE))
```

I tried several times, with grouped data or sorted data. I do not know what is wrong with the second method. Is it because the NA values I have got in my data frame? but the first method is fine?

Since I have quite a lot more information in my data frame waiting to be analysed, I do not want to extract vectors for every single of them. I hope to do my paired t-test on my data frame. Could anyone help me?

the detail of centre_g is:

```
structure(list(day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), SAMPLE.No = structure(c(1L, 
13L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 
1L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 3L), .Label = c("s1", 
"s1.2", "s10", "s10.2", "s11", "s11.2", "s12", "s12.2", "s13", 
"s13.2", "s14", "s14.2", "s2", "s2.2", "s3", "s3.2", "s4", "s4.2", 
"s5", "s5.2", "s6", "s6.2", "s7", "s7.2", "s8", "s8.2", "s9", 
"s9.2"), class = "factor"), weir = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
11L, 12L, 12L), BA = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("after", "before"), class = "factor"), centre.bank = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("bank", "centre"), class = "factor"), 
    Pb = c(436.65, 1182.93, 1465.21, 3105.36, 39.1, 1493.91, 
    NA, 165.28, 38.83, 351.48, 80.26, 47.39, 151.27, 434.01, 
    -97.58, 240.83, 56.8, 40.24, 38.8, NA, 41.13, 38.93, 44.39, 
    39.05), Pb.Error = c(16.41, 30.01, 51.26, 102.44, 27.21, 
    79.63, NA, 13.82, 48.78, 16.71, 19.1, 21.43, 18.65, 21.41, 
    232.7, 18.83, 12.19, 15.28, 11.94, NA, 22.24, 14.01, 10.56, 
    9.63), Zn = c(542.52, 981.83, 1234.78, 7554.41, 529.38, 5240.01, 
    NA, 542.65, 526.08, 820.87, 649.7, 793.42, 707.23, 1204.3, 
    -34.56, 209.86, 172.5, 130.29, 187.96, NA, 234.57, 137.38, 
    165.21, 135.05), Zn.Error = c(19.5, 29.31, 48.12, 161.54, 
    42.36, 144.56, NA, 23.37, 52.5, 26.18, 33.33, 39.87, 31.89, 
    35.79, 44.83, 17.24, 15.11, 21.25, 19.76, NA, 26.65, 18.67, 
    15.12, 13.97), Fe = c(3731.23, 14239.54, 23774.52, 52349.37, 
    3896.63, 13311.26, NA, 2756.96, 3511.06, 2664.12, 2383.16, 
    2785.75, 2834.59, 6288.39, -321.14, 14704.05, 3825.8, 5017.52, 
    13181.67, NA, 31190.39, 8516.23, 14130, 18348.01), Fe.Error = c(106.82, 
    229.87, 432.59, 884.29, 239.03, 496.1, NA, 111.92, 283.9, 
    102.44, 137.69, 161.02, 137.66, 172.32, 187.37, 274.6, 140.64, 
    240.97, 310.62, NA, 565.41, 265.57, 260.75, 291.45), Mn = c(110.65, 
    1337.08, 1126.82, 3495.03, 410.99, 5267.34, NA, 314.42, 338.8, 
    591.99, 308.46, 427.59, 573.87, 896.23, 277.82, 421.17, 969.72, 
    535.07, 879.97, NA, 742.39, 350.62, 379.98, 834.36), Mn.Error = c(43.39, 
    93.86, 133.34, 297.53, 125.08, 410.14, NA, 63.25, 155.08, 
    68.16, 82.1, 96.34, 88.97, 89.89, 1470.88, 78, 92.24, 118.6, 
    112.32, NA, 134.87, 91.97, 72.7, 91.12), Cr = c(-38.15, 50.8, 
    25.9, 53.32, 21.52, 132.82, NA, 8.13, 5.46, 35.07, 93.78, 
    88.18, 71.23, 47.26, 32.91, 25.49, 10.36, 19.99, 5.13, NA, 
    32.61, 22.13, 47.5, -5.82), Cr.Error = c(9.05, 16.41, 7.7, 
    9.99, 4.58, 33.88, NA, 7.84, 2.86, 9.18, 8.75, 7.55, 7.98, 
    9.62, 6.38, 5.54, 6.72, 4.6, 6.5, NA, 6.64, 4.62, 9.51, 11.3
    ), Ca = c(32195.21, 46510.98, 21723.24, 17820.74, 14639.01, 
    45937.9, NA, 37840.08, 4704.64, 37705.36, 28625.21, 25115.24, 
    41579.19, 91829.16, 19752.96, 14605.4, 34654.73, 15798.87, 
    13873.07, NA, 22901.14, 4097.09, 12053.38, 276525.69), Ca.Error = c(211.2, 
    326.69, 160.54, 142.76, 120.63, 304.76, NA, 219.4, 66.28, 
    225.41, 187.03, 169.88, 226.15, 378.53, 149.92, 125.47, 208.18, 
    127.73, 127.4, NA, 168.31, 64.51, 128.02, 908.61)), row.names = c(1L, 
4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 26L, 28L, 
29L, 32L, 34L, 36L, 38L, 39L, 42L, 43L, 46L, 48L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am interested in doing paired t test on "Pb" column, trying to compare "before" and "after" (as shown in column "BA"). Each "weir" would be an individual.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `centre_g` here using the output from `dput`?

Comment: Hey I tried to do that. I now put the content in the description. I altered the output a little bit since there are a lot of other variables. Hope there's no mistake during alternation.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing `)` somewhere in that `dput` output. I added one at the end and am now getting a list that I don't think is your intended data

Comment: thank you @camille. My intended data is the "BA" column and "Pb" column. I grouped the data frame based on "BA". That's basicly what I did. If that is understandable?

Comment: Your approach is clear enough, but there's a typo in the data sample you posted, such that a `)` is missing somewhere and I'm not sure where

Comment: @camille I pasted the code, and found the problem too. Now I just uploaded the whole dataset in case I am missing anything. BTW I already worked out this question. Adding na.rm = FALSE to avoid R mistakenly taking my NA data away helps to keep the variables the same length under different factors.

Answer (score 2):

I have worked it our after a day. I found it is because a row of NA data. There are some places where I did not manage to take samples, so there appears to be a whole row of NA data (except the factors columns).

To make sure the data frame has the whole length (24 instead of 23) and does not omit NA data, add na.rm = FALSE when subsetting the data frame into centre_g.

```
centre_g <- subset(HM_selected, centre.bank == "centre", na.rm = FALSE)
```

(I think I gave the right centre_g in my question dataset, but occationally I just got 23 data. adding na.rm to make sure how NA data are processed)

When doing the paired t-test, also add na.rm = FALSE.

```
(tRESULT <- t.test(Pb ~ BA, data = centre, paired = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)
```

and that works perfectly for me.

- sorry if there is any confusion in the question